# Can I recover someone's WhatsApp chat history after I've mistakenly changed phone numbers?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, history

I've got all someone's chat history on my WhatsApp number after trying to help her when her phone broke.  I want to get it back onto her WhatsApp number - can anyone help?

When her phone broke, I tried to help out by lending her my phone. I used WhatsApp's Change Number feature to change from my number to hers.  Then when I got her a new phone, I used Change Number to go back to my number.  But I didn't realise Change Number changes the number in all Chats and Groups.  All her chats and groups now have my number in them.  So now I get my messages, plus any from her Chats and Groups and I have her entire history on my number.

Can anyone see a way to untangle this mess?  I'm in a lot of trouble.

Things I have tried:

- She has set up WhatsApp on her new phone with her original number but the history is gone.
- I've looked at restoring an old version of her WhatsApp backup - but I think her history has been over-written by recent backups after this mess happened. I can't find any previous versions on Google Drive.
- I looked at transferring my backup to her, but don't think this is possible.
- I said I could email her individual chat histories - she wasn't impressed.

Any ideas are welcome. Both our phones are Android.

Comment: my opinion: unregister all phone numbers and uninstall WhatsApp on both phones. Don't ever use any facebook apps at all. In case you wanna fiddle with databases [TripCode](https://forum.xda-developers.com/search/34183555) and [ztedd](https://forum.xda-developers.com/search/34183501) have good base to start